# Multiple panels in iOS Xamarin app

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I need to have application which is changing its visual content. I am creating this app in Xamarin in C# language and I need some collection of panels on which I can put my controls and switch visibility of these controls based on action of user. What is the best approach to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you watch the different examples, read the code, probe the examples in the official page of Xamarin.

[examples](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/)

and because you are new donwload this book, is the best for start

[book](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/)

This community in StackOverflow like Questions with a better information, try to effort to write better, and explain the most exactly possible for the people can help you. Regards I hope this help.